# helm search functionality not fetching results from repo

Tags: kubernetes-helm

```
▶ helm version --tls
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.9.1", GitCommit:"20adb27c7c5868466912eebdf6664e7390ebe710", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.11.0", GitCommit:"2e55dbe1fdb5fdb96b75ff144a339489417b146b", GitTreeState:"clean"}

~
▶ helm repo list
NAME        URL
stable      https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
incubator   https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-charts-incubator
stakater    https://stakater.github.io/stakater-charts
flagger     https://flagger.app
bitnami     https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami

~
▶ helm repo update --debug
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "flagger" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stakater" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "incubator" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "bitnami" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈ Happy Helming!⎈

~
▶ helm search repo bitnami/postgresql
No results found

~
▶ helm search repo bitnami/mariadb -l
No results found
```

However this works (have to escape `~` on `zsh`)

```
▶ helm search postgresql --version \~8.9.0
NAME                CHART VERSION   APP VERSION DESCRIPTION
bitnami/postgresql  8.9.9           11.8.0      Chart for PostgreSQL, an object-relational data...
```

How can I specify a repo to search in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the Helm repo search functionality only available since v3.0.0.

Even I tried using the latest v2.16.7 version, still no luck.

```
$ helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.16.7", GitCommit:"5f2584fd3d35552c4af26036f0c464191287986b", GitTreeState:"clean"}"

$ helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
"bitnami" has been added to your repositories

$ helm repo update --debug
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Skip local chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "bitnami" chart repository
Update Complete.

$ helm repo list          
NAME    URL                                             
stable  https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
local   http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts                    
bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami 

$ helm search repo bitnami/postgresql
No results found
```

But it works well with version 3.0.0 or above.

```
$ helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.0.0", GitCommit:"e29ce2a54e96cd02ccfce88bee4f58bb6e2a28b6", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.4"}

$ helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
"bitnami" has been added to your repositories

$ helm repo update --debug
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "bitnami" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈ Happy Helming!⎈ 

$ helm repo list
NAME    URL                               
bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami

$ helm search repo bitnami/postgresql
NAME                    CHART VERSION   APP VERSION     DESCRIPTION                                       
bitnami/postgresql      8.10.2          11.8.0          Chart for PostgreSQL, an object-relational data...
bitnami/postgresql-ha   3.2.7           11.8.0          Chart for PostgreSQL with HA architecture (usin...
```

Comment: This actually is incorrect, helm search in a given repo is available in helm 2 and helm 3. The difference is that the command format is different. The helm 2 command is just `helm search`, the helm 3 command is `helm search repo`. So, when you run `helm search repo ...` with helm 2, it is actually using `repo` as part of the search string.

`
❯ helm2.14.3 search bitnami/postgresql
NAME                  CHART VERSION APP VERSION DESCRIPTION
bitnami/postgresql    11.2.6        14.3.0      PostgreSQL (Postgres) is an open source object-relational...
`